# openjpa criteria builder and or

Tags: java, openjpa

Hi i need to do a complex query, with and or condition. But the and condition seems to override the or condition here's my code:

```
public List<UtenteEntity> search(CartesioPojo params) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UtenteEntity> q = cb.createQuery(UtenteEntity.class);
    Root<UtenteEntity> c = q.from(UtenteEntity.class);
    UtenteParams utente = (UtenteParams) params;
    List<Predicate> p = new Vector<Predicate>();
    if(utente.getUsername() != null && !utente.getUsername().equals(""))
        p.add(cb.equal(c.get("username"), cb.literal(utente.getUsername())));
    if(utente.getCognome() != null && !utente.getCognome().equals(""))
        p.add(cb.and(cb.equal(c.get("cognome"), cb.literal(utente.getCognome()))));
    if(utente.getRoles() != null && !utente.getRoles().isEmpty()) {
        for (RuoloEntity ruolo : utente.getRoles()) {
            p.add(cb.or(cb.equal(c.get("ruolo"), cb.literal(ruolo))));
        }
    }
    q.where(p.toArray(new Predicate[p.size()]));
    q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get(USERNAME_COLUMN)));
    TypedQuery<UtenteEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
    List<UtenteEntity> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

this is the console output when I exceute this method:

```
executing prepstmnt 2471808 SELECT t0.SEQU_LONG_ID, t0.DATA_AGGIORNAMENTO, 
t0.DATA_CREAZIONE, t0.FK_UTENTE_AGGIORNAMENTO, t0.FK_UTENTE_CREAZIONE, t0.COGNOME, 
t0.FLAG_DISABILITATO, t0.NOME, t0.PASSWORD, t1.SEQU_LONG_ID, t1.DATA_AGGIORNAMENTO, 
t1.DATA_CREAZIONE, t1.FK_UTENTE_AGGIORNAMENTO, t1.FK_UTENTE_CREAZIONE, t1.CODICE, 
t1.DESCRIZIONE, t0.USERNAME FROM UTENTE t0, RUOLO t1 WHERE 
(t0.FK_RUOLO = ? AND t0.FK_RUOLO = ?) AND t0.FK_RUOLO = t1.SEQU_LONG_ID(+) 
ORDER BY t0.USERNAME ASC [params=?, ?]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the list of predicates, you're adding, in a loop, an or clause containing a single element:

```
 p.add(cb.or(cb.equal(c.get("ruolo"), cb.literal(ruolo))));
```

What you want is to create a list of predicates joined with or, and adding this long `or` predicate to the main list:

```
List<Predicate> disjunction = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
for (RuoloEntity ruolo : utente.getRoles()) {
    disjunction.add(cb.equal(c.get("ruolo"), cb.literal(ruolo)));
}
p.add(cb.or(disjunction.toArray(new Predicate[disjunction.size()])));
```